# Create or update bulk objects with association

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I use `INSERT` with `ON CONFLICT` for create or update data.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO users(office_id, f_name, l_name)
VALUES
  (1, 'user1_f', 'u1_last'),
  (2, 'user2_f', 'u2_last'),
  (2, 'user3_f', 'u2_last')
ON CONFLICT(office_id, l_name)
DO UPDATE SET
  f_name=EXCLUDED.f_name
```

But can I create also associated to `users` for example `profiles` table if user wasn't exist?

I mean if I don't have conflict, will be

`INSERT INTO profiles(user_id, url)
VALUES(user_id, 'google.com')` and `user_id` will be `id` from created user

I dont know is it possible. Thanks.

Comment: why not just do both inserts with cte?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it through Postgres `WITH` from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html in next way:

```
WITH new_users AS (
  INSERT INTO users(office_id, f_name, l_name)
  VALUES
    (1, 'user1_f', 'u1_last'),
    (2, 'user2_f', 'u2_last'),
    (2, 'user3_f', 'u2_last')
  ON CONFLICT(office_id, l_name)
  DO UPDATE SET
    f_name=EXCLUDED.f_name
  RETURNING *
), new_user_profile AS (
  INSERT INTO profiles(user_id, created_at, updated_at)
  SELECT id, current_timestamp, current_timestamp FROM new_users
  ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO NOTHING
  RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM new_users
```